# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Bigl[\bigl(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\bigr)\bigl(\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{(\cos{x})^{2n}}{2^x}\,dx\bigr)\Bigr]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, improper-integrals, contest-math

The following calculus problem is from the Stanford Math Tournament, 2013 #10.

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\left(\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{(\cos{x})^{2n}}{2^x}\,dx\right)\right]$$

I've had immense difficulty with this problem, and I wasn't really able to understand the solutions to this problem provided by Stanford. Hopefully you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Edit: Okay, to the person who voted my question to be closed because it was deemed off-topic and did not provide enough context: there's not really much I can say about my own approach to this question since it is beyond my level. I'm pretty much clueless about where to even begin, so sorry about that.

Comment: Huh, that's degenerative. Thanks for the heads up, I'll make an edit.

Comment: The integral is converging to zero, so in order for this question to be non trivial, the product must be going to infinity.

Comment: @Mark: Is there anything we can do with that information?

Comment: It seems we would like to pull the product inside the integral so that the limit can stabilize.

Comment: Do you think you can show your work to elaborate on this idea? Sorry for my lack of understanding..

Comment: I see that you have already selected an answer, but my idea is that the cosines form some sort of dirac integral at the points $\pi k$, since the peaks blow up and everything else goes to zero. The other idea is to use a change of variables around one of the peaks to make it flatter but wider. You can imagine that once we do that, each peak will sort of look like a normal density function. My answer has more details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The product is equal to

$$\frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} $$

which behaves as $\sqrt{\pi n}$ as $n \to \infty$.  As for the integral, rewrite as

$$\int_{-1}^0 dx \, 2^{-x} \cos^{2 n}{x} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-\pi k} \int_0^{\pi} dx \, 2^{-x} \cos^{2 n}{x}$$

Rewrite in a form useful for Watson's Lemma:

$$\int_{-1}^0 dx \, 2^{-x} e^{2 n \log{(\cos{x})}} + \frac1{1-2^{-\pi}}\left [  \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, 2^{-x} e^{2 n \log{(\cos{x})}}+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} dx \, 2^{-x} e^{2 n \log{(-\cos{x})}}\right ]$$

or

$$\int_{-1}^0 dx \, 2^{-x} e^{2 n \log{(\cos{x})}} + \frac1{1-2^{-\pi}}\left [  \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, 2^{-x} e^{2 n \log{(\cos{x})}}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2} dx \, 2^{x} e^{2 n \log{(\cos{x})}}\right ]$$

The maximum of the argument of the exponential in each integral occurs at $x=0$.  About $x=0$, $\log{(\cos{x})} \sim -x^2/2$.  By Watson's Lemma, we may extend the interval of integration in each integral out to infinity with exponentially small error as $n \to \infty$.  Thus, each integral behaves as $\frac12 \sqrt{\pi/n}$ in this limit.  Note, however, that there is no contribution from the integral over $[-1,0]$ because its contribution is subsumed in the first integral over $[0,\pi/2]$ because $1 \lt \pi/2$.  Thus, the sought-after limit is

$$\sqrt{\pi n} \frac{1}{1-2^{-\pi}}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}} = \frac{\pi}{1-2^{-\pi}} $$

**ADDENDUM**

Likely closer to the problem-poser's intent is the observation that

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2 k}{2 k-1} = \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} $$

and, as $n \to \infty$,

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \, 2^{-x} \cos^{2 n}{x} \sim \int_0^{\pi} dx \, \cos^{2 n}{x} = \frac{\pi }{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n} $$

The result follows.

Comment: Hi Ron. According to Stanford's provided solutions, the answer is supposed to be $$\pi\frac{2^\pi}{2^\pi - 1}$$

Comment: @user155812: I realized my mistake before you posted your comment.  I hope my analysis is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you, Ron. Your solution is very much comprehensive and appreciated.

Comment: Also, do you think you could explain how/why you are able to rewrite the integral partially using the sigma summation?

Comment: @user155812: I write it that way because the cosine is periodic and thus experiences maxima at regular intervals along the $x$ axis.  Thus, to apply Watson's Lemma, we need to treat each of these maxima separately.

Comment: How come one of the limits of integration is $\pi$, though?

Comment: @user155812: The period of $\cos^2{x}$ is $\pi$, but then I wanted to further rewrite the integral to account for the different behaviors of the cosine over the first and second halves of the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

I will use $I$ as the indicator function.

When $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\cos(x)^{2n} = I[x = \pi k]_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ so when $n$ is large, the only points that really matter are multiples of $\pi$. For this reason, write $\cos(x) = \cos(x)(I_{S_\epsilon} + I_{S_\epsilon ^c})(x)$ where $S_\epsilon$ is the set of all real numbers within $\epsilon$ distance of a multiple of $\pi$ which are greater than $-1$.

Note $\cos(x)^{2n} = \cos^{2n}(x)I_{S_\epsilon}(x) + \cos^{2n}(x)I_{S_\epsilon ^c}(x)$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\left(\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{(\cos{x})^{2n}}{2^x}\,dx\right)\right] = $$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\left(\int_{I_{S_\epsilon}}\frac{ \cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx\right)\right] + \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\left(\int_{I_{S_\epsilon ^c}}\frac{ \cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx\right)\right]$$

Let's call $p = \cos(\epsilon)$ so that $p \lt 1$. Then $\cos^{2n}(x)I_{S_\epsilon ^c}(x) < p^{2n}.$
Now since the product is bounded by $K\sqrt{n}$ we may compute the second term as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\left(\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{ \cos^{2n}(x)I_{S_\epsilon ^c}(x)}{2^x}\,dx\right)\right] \le  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{ K p^{2n}\sqrt{n}}{2^x}\,dx = 0$$

where the right hand side $=0$ is obtained by monotone convergence theorem.

Now we estimate the first term $\int_{I_{S_\epsilon}}\frac{( \prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{2k}{2k-1}})\cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}dx$ as $n$ grows large. Now I will be a little sloppy with estimates to motivate the solution. Note the product becomes close to $\sqrt{\pi n}$ as Ron Gordon's solution states. The integral will be close to

$$\int_{I_{S_\epsilon}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}\cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx$$

$$\sum_{k \ge 0} \int_{\pi k - \epsilon} ^{\pi k + \epsilon}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}\cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx$$

Now concentrate on one of the terms in the sum

$$\int_{\pi k - \epsilon} ^{\pi k + \epsilon}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}\cos^{2n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2^{\pi k}}\int_{- \epsilon} ^{ \epsilon}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}\cos^{2n}(x)}{2^{x}}\,dx$$

Substituting $x = \arcsin(u)$

$$\frac{1}{2^{\pi k}} \int_{-\sin(\epsilon)}^{\sin(\epsilon)}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}(1 - {u}^2)^{n - \frac{1}{2}}}{2^{\arcsin { u}}}\,du$$

Further substituting $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} v = u$

$$\frac{1}{2^{\pi k}} \int_{- \sqrt{\pi n} \sin(\epsilon)}^{\sqrt{\pi n} \sin(\epsilon)}\frac{(1 - \frac{v^2}{\pi n})^{n - \frac{1}{2}}}{2^{\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} v}}\,dv$$

By noting that for some $C \gt 0$, $|\frac{(1 - \frac{v^2}{\pi n})^{- \frac{1}{2}}}{2^{\arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} v}} - 1| \lt C \epsilon$ uniformly inside the domain of integration, so we can choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that the term in question is arbitrarily close to 1. Hence we have

$$\approx \frac{1}{2^{\pi k}} \int_{- \sqrt{\pi n} \sin(\epsilon)}^{\sqrt{\pi n} \sin(\epsilon)}(1 - \frac{v^2}{\pi n})^{n}\,dv$$

Write $(1 - \frac{v^2}{\pi n})^{n}$ as $e^{n \log(1 - \frac{v^2}{\pi n})} $. Expanding $\log(1 + x) = x - x^2 g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is analytic around $0$ and $g(0) = 1/2$ We get $e^{n (- \frac{v^2}{\pi n} - \frac{v^4}{\pi^2 n^2} g(\frac{v^2}{\pi n}))} = e^{- \frac{v^2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{v^4}{\pi^2 n} g(\frac{v^2}{\pi n})}$  Inside the domain of integration $|g(\frac{v^2}{\pi n}) - 1/2| \lt C\epsilon$ and $|\frac{v^4}{\pi n^2}| \le \pi^2 n \sin(\epsilon)^4$ If we allow $\epsilon$ to be a function of $n$ and write $\epsilon_n = \sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}$, this will bound $e^{-\frac{v^4}{\pi^2 n}}$ close to 1 inside the region of integration.

$$\approx \frac{1}{2^{\pi k}} \int_{- \sqrt{\pi n}\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}}^{\sqrt{\pi n} \sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}}e^{-v^2 / \pi}\,dv$$

$$\approx \frac{1}{2^{\pi k}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}e^{-v^2 / \pi}\,dv$$

Now 
Recognizing the gaussian integral, 
$$\approx 2^{-\pi k} \pi$$

So taking the sum we get
$$=\pi \sum_{k \ge 0} (2^{-\pi})^k $$
$$=\pi \frac{1}{1-2^{-\pi}}$$

Now we must go back to check that our definition of $\epsilon_n$ did not break the first computation of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-1}^{\infty}\frac{ K p^{2n}\sqrt{n}}{2^x}\,dx$ since $p = \cos(\epsilon)$ is now a function of $n$. But we get $K p_n ^{2n} \sqrt{n} = K ({\log n / n})^n \sqrt{n}$ so we can still use monotone convergence theorem.

There is also the technicality of taking the limit inside the infinite sum, but we can look back on our estimates and see that they were all uniform in $k$ since we did not appeal to the value of $k$ at all.